# Как виджет menu упаковать в низ окна tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Чтоб упаковать виджет *tk.Menu*, обычно надо изменить свойство окна *menu*:

```
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    rMenu = tk.Menu()
    rMenu.add_cascade(label="(Меню)")
    root.config(menu=rMenu)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Таким образом на верху образуется виджет *tk.Menu*, но как его
упаковать внизу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак, если мы говорим о нативном меню, которое устанавливается через атрибут `menu` окна. Потому как в этом случае используется меню для окон, которое предоставляет операционная система.

Можно создать собственное "типа" меню, которое будет более или менее похоже на настоящее, на основе `frame` и менюшных кнопок. И поместить его уже куда угодно.